# Prevent jquery-mobile popup repositions for Huawei phones after text is entered to an input element

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, popup, huawei-mobile-services

in our project we are utilizing the [jquery-mobile popup dialog](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/popup/)

Once the dialog is shown, the first time I attempt to fill in the text on my phone (Huawei P9 lite, Android 6.0.0, Chrome 55.0.2883.91), the popup closes and reopens.

I am able to replicate this issue even on the demo **Form** popup.

On a sightly larger device (5.7 inches vs 5 inches) with a larger screen and almost the same android (6.0.1, the same browser) this does not happen.

**It seems to be caused by popup automatically repositioning after the keyboard appears. Did anyone encounter a similar problem? How did u solve it?**

```
<a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a" data-transition="pop">Sign in</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
    <form>
        <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
            <h3>Please sign in</h3>
            <label for="un" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="user" id="un" value="" placeholder="username" data-theme="a">
            <label for="pw" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="pw" value="" placeholder="password" data-theme="a">
            <button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check">Sign in</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: use a page with data-role="dialog", as you have anyway data-position-to="window" in your project

Comment: Thanks a lot, since we have a decent amount of these, I will attempt to find a quick workaround instead of reworking all the popups

Comment: @deblocker dialogs will be removed in next version.

Comment: @Omar: THX for correcting my mistake, my intention was to suggest to use a page with data-dialog="true", this is working already in 1.4.5 and AFAIK will be supported also in 1.5 - you confirm?

Comment: @deblocker no worries :) I'm not sure if that would fix OP's problem. It's all about some code attached to resize event. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/e377564aa121d0439a21bc97f7854ee618c3f72d/js/widgets/popup.js#L367

Comment: @Omar thanks for this, for now its the most I received for my 50 points :) 
Hard and way too specific question I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is based on Omar's comment. Once I comment the following lines of code the behavior does not appear (there is a possible loss of a nice repositioning feature).

```
_handleWindowResize: function(/* theEvent */) {
    if ( this._isOpen && this._ignoreResizeTo === 0 ) {
        if ( ( this._expectResizeEvent() || this._orientationchangeInProgress ) &&
            !this._ui.container.hasClass( "ui-popup-hidden" ) ) {
            // effectively rapid-close the popup while leaving the screen intact
            // this._ui.container
            //  .addClass( "ui-popup-hidden ui-popup-truncate" )
            //  .removeAttr( "style" );
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: you can add reposition function in place of the commented code.

Comment: @Omar: i guess this has been fixed for 1.5, at least from the changelog here [jQuery Mobile 1.5.0-alpha1 Changelog](http://jquerymobile.com/changelog/1.5.0-alpha1/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing @deblocker. Unfortunately, It is not released yet.